# externalcontrol URCap from ur_robot_driver cannot establish connection with host pc

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, universal-robot, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the externalcontrol node on the UR5 robot, but I get the following message:

```
"The connection to the remote PC could not be established"
```

Things to note:

- I calibrated my robot before starting ur_robot_driver on my PC
- After starting ur_robot_driver (and MoveIt) I see the correct state of the physical robot in Rviz
- I doublechecked the IP-address of my ROS PC in externalcontrol under the installation tab on the tablet

Robot specifications:

- UR5
- CB3.0 controller
- PolyScope 3.9.1
- External Control URcap version 1.0.1

ROS PC specifications:

- Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial
- ROS Kinetic
- ur_robot_driver version 0.0.3

What did I wrong?
The ROS driver is running on the pc and the host IP address is correct.

EDIT:
`ip_addr_show` outputs this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:f6:77:99:da:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.69.4/19 brd 192.168.95.255 scope global dynamic wlp3s0
       valid_lft 10244sec preferred_lft 10244sec
    inet6 fe80::ba57:b562:9c11:3b9b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enx3c18a078b201: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:18:a0:78:b2:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enx3c18a078b201
       valid_lft 86378sec preferred_lft 86378sec
    inet6 fe80::13f6:65f:11df:fc3e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341317/externalcontrol-urcap-from-ur_robot_driver-cannot-establish-connection-with-host-pc/) by [krablander](https://answers.ros.org/users/50137/krablander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2020-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-09**:
Could you tell us whether you have a firewall enabled? And whether you are running Ubuntu natively, or in a VM?

> I doublechecked the IP-address of my ROS PC in externalcontrol

probably, but please show us the IPs and network settings of the hosts involved.

**Comment by [krablander](https://answers.ros.org/users/50137/krablander/) on 2020-01-09**:
The firewall is disabled. I am running Ubuntu natively on the PC (dualboot with windows).

- IP-address of the host pc: 192.168.69.4 (DHCP, found by command hostname -I)
- IP-address of the robot: 192.168.1.200 (static)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-09**:\

> DHCP, found by command hostname -I

please note that for multi-homed hosts this may not return the correct IP.

Could you show the output of `ip addr show`?

And [UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver#74](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/issues/74) is a recent thread with a similar issue. See some of the later comments with steps to diagnose connection issues.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-09**:
Given this: `192.168.69.4/19` I'm curious how you can access `192.168.1.200`. Is there a (NAT) router between you and the robot? Can you show the output of: `tracepath 192.168.1.200`?

**Comment by [krablander](https://answers.ros.org/users/50137/krablander/) on 2020-01-09**:
There is a router between the ROS PC and the robot.
`tracepath 192.168.1.200` outputs this:

```
1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
1:  192.168.1.200                                         3.091ms reached
1:  192.168.1.200                                         1.933ms reached
Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 1 back 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What sort of router? Do you mean a switch? Because from the `tracepath` output it doesn't look like there is a router. I would've expected to see a hop between you and the robot in that case with a different IP address.

Could you tell us what sort of computers are involved? A laptop? A desktop PC? Is there a wireless link involved?

Could you also login to the robot (using SSH, user: `root`, pass: `easybot`) and try to `ping 192.168.69.4`? Also try: `nc 192.168.69.4 50002` when you have the driver running on the ROS side. If that doesn't connect or time-out (it can take a while, up to 2.5 minutes), it would indicate something is blocking connections between the robot controller and the ROS PC.

Right now I believe you're using the wrong IP address for the reverse connection (ie: the one from the robot controller to the PC).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krablander](https://answers.ros.org/users/50137/krablander/) on 2020-01-10**:
I am using a linksys e1200 router. I am using a laptop with a USB-C -> ethernet adapter.
There are no wireless links involved.

```
Laptop -> UTP cable -> router -> UTP cable -> UR5 robot
```

I pinged and nc'd `192.168.69.4` from the robot side, this gave me a time-out.
However, after trying to ping another IP address `192.168.1.100`, it was connecting.

So I changed the IP address from `192.168.69.4` to `192.168.1.100` in externalcontrol, the driver was running with no problems.
I think the issue has been resolved.
Thank you for your assistance.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2020-12-28**:
I am having exactly the same problem.
Also, when I run `nc 192.168.0.77 50002` (my host IP address is 192.168.0.77), I get following error `(UNKNOWN) [192.168.0.77] 50002 (?) : Connection refused`. Any suggestion please?

**Comment by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on 2022-06-01**:
I have the same problem. Connection refused. Did you find a solution?